# How to send and receive data from the REST service (JavaFX, RestEasy, Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx, resteasy

I create app in Spring Boot and JavaFX as a client. I'm using RestEasy to sending and receiving data from REST service. When I don't using Spring Security, data is normally sent and received. When I add Spring Security I don't have access to data and I don't know how to get to them using RestEasy.

My test REST Api:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity test(@RequestBody Usr usr) {
    System.out.println(usr);
    return new ResponseEntity("Ok", HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity test2() {
    System.out.println("Test2");
    return new ResponseEntity("OkGet", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

My code, that connect with this:

On /test endpoint:

```
ClientRequest clientRequest = new ClientRequest(applicationUrl);
clientRequest.body("application/json", usr);
String o = (String)clientRequest.post(Usr.class).getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println("Resp: " + o);
```

On /test2 endpoint:

```
ClientRequest clientRequest = new ClientRequest(applicationUrl2);
String o = (String)clientRequest.get().getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println("Resp: " + o);
```

This code working when I don't using Spring Secuirty.

I'm trying something like this but don't working, return empty string and on server side the data in the console does not print out:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope("localhost", 8090),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("a", "a")
    );
ApacheHttpClient4Executor executor = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(client);
ClientRequest clientRequest = new ClientRequest(applicationUrl2, executor);
String o = (String)clientRequest.get().getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println("Resp: " + o);
```

**Update - add Spring Security configuration**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/test", "/test2").authenticated()
            .and().formLogin();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("a")
            .password("{noop}a")
            .roles("USER");
}
```

Comment: Post your security configuration, without it we cannot help. Most probably some spring security interceptor is blocking your requests.

Comment: @Nadir configuration is added above.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution. I removed `.formLogin()` and add

```
.and().httpBasic()
.and().csrf().disable();
```

The first problem was probably redirection to the login page and then the lack of authorization.
I will leave the post, it may be useful to someone. :D